# How to transfer data into empty modal fields?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I´m making a adress book. I have already a working modal which pops up when creating a new contact.

But i haven´t found any possibility to "edit contact" with an modal. So that the existing contact (name, email, resident...) is transfered into the empty modal fields to edit and then save.

Every contact is a own id which is generated automaticly when creating. I have no problems with the transfering of the data when i use a regular extra html page by clicking "edit contact". But the modal gives me problems.

I`m creating a new edit button for every new contact

```
// edit button
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.onclick = function() {
    window.location.href='KontaktBearbeiten.html?id=' + kontakt.id;

};
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = "images/edit.png";
image.width = "15";
image.height = "15";
button.appendChild(image);
td.appendChild(button);
```

Is there any possibility to pre-occupy fields in a modal?

Comment: set the value of the fields in the model to some default value like document.getElementById('model_field').value="0" and there is an attribute called `editable` I have seen it used somewhere idk if its completely valid here

Comment: If you are changing pages to edit then you are showing us the wrong code. The button isn't relevant, the other page is